# File which contains table_names and column_names in it. Now i want to pull this two values into two variables and loop them

Tags: text-processing

I have file called `objects.txt` contains tables and columns as below.

```
Part:1
Table_name: customer1
Column_name: account_no

Part:2
Table_name: customer2
Column_name: purchase_id
.
.
Part:n
```

Now, I want to pick this table_name and column_name from the file as two variables in a loop and send to the `sqlplus` to run the below query.

```
For tab in grep of table_name
For col in grep of column_name

Set table=$tab
Set column=$col
Set Null_check='sqlplus -s/@$oracle' ‹‹ENDOFSQL
set serveroutput on;
Select count(*) from (select $column from $table where $column is null);
Exit
ENDOFSQL
```

Please help me how to loop the this two variables in single for loop iteration and send to this SQL query

Comment: Any alternate way as i need to pass the two variables by taking from the objects.txt file. For suppose i greping table and column and keeping into two variables.      For TAB in grep 'table_name:' objects.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2 | awk '{print $1}'     For COL in grep 'column_name:' objects.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2 | awk '{print $1}        Now, i want to pass this TAB and COL variables into loop following by the sqlplus query to check the NULLs. Please help in looping this two variables

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
function insert {
    printf "Table: %s Column: %s\n" $1 $2
}

while read prefix rest
do
    case $prefix in
        'Table_name:') 
            table=$rest
            ;;
        'Column_name:') 
            column=$rest
            insert $table $column
            ;;
        *)
            ;;
    esac
done < datafile
```

Where you replace `insert` with a function that uses the two parameters to run the SQL requests.